# How to manage simultanious network connections in Windows 10 by application/program?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, internet-connection

Is there method, tool or solution out there that allows users to configure routes to the internet by program/application in Windows 10, where there are multiple connected networks?

For example, let's say I connect to two separate networks, one over WiFi and the other over Ethernet, and both supply internet access. I understand Windows 10 assigns 'gateway priority' which forces all traffic to go through the connection with higher priority.

Is there a way to specify which app uses a specific connection? In other words, is it possible to configure a single program (say a game) to use the Ethernet network, while everything else uses WiFi?

Comment: I don't think Windows has a tool to do that, not even in Server, unless you count load balancing as the proper tool, but then it takes some serious tinkering. Some programs allow you to choose an Internet interface to connect through. qBittorrent, for example, will let you do that. There are or were third-parties that could help you do that, but I'm not sure they'll work with Windows 10. See here for a non-exhaustive list: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/

Comment: Thanks @Didier, looks like ForceBindIP has potential. There's also an open source 'successor' (https://github.com/katlogic/bindip) but it doesn't support win10 either.